# How to create liferay theme from scratch?

Tags: themes, liferay

I am new to Liferay , is there any good article available for Creating theme for Lifefay 5.2.

and also how to convert theme to ***.war** file

Comment: thanks all finally created two themes and contributed in liferay community HTML5 initializr theme http://goo.gl/MyHf4 and smashing html5 theme http://goo.gl/0buEE :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [liferay plugins SDK](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/downloads/additional) is a good environment for developing themes. The [Liferay Wiki](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Themes#section-Themes-DevelopingATheme) has some quick start information about how to use it, also about how to configure liferay to be able to edit the theme "in place". The [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/documentation/5_2) (especially the development documentation, even if it's for 5.1) has more in depth information.

There are Ant Scripts that come with the Plugins SDK that create the *.war file for you. They also do a good job separating your changes from the default theme of/in liferay (as your changes are stored in a "diff" folder, thus easily identifiable. When defaults change, you may need to adapt your changes, but you know exactly what parts you have changed.

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a tutorial that explains [how to create a Liferay theme](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/11/30/styling-liferay-creating-a-liferay-theme/). I was working with Liferay 6.0 at the time of writing, but the article should be good for people still using Liferay 5.2 as well.

Comment: thanks for sharing link and details about creating Liferay theme

Comment: @Integrating Stuff:
Very nice article. I am following other articles too on the site.
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Users of NetBeans may also want to look at this Netbeans.org article:

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/portal-pack-themes.html#giquj

You'll need to have downloaded and manually installed the appropriate modules for PortalPack (since I cannot post a second link in a single answer yet, you'll have to google "Portal Pack")